# Retrieving data from a Facebook GraphObject

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-php-sdk

I have looked around and tried several things, converting it to array and trying to access the object directly.

I want to take out the page ID, name and access token.

Here is my code to get the object with the pages I look after:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/'.$userID .'/accounts');

$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

I get the following array using `$array =  (array) $graphObject;`:

```
Array([*backingData] => Array(
    [data] => Array(
        [0] => stdClass Object(
            [access_token] => CAAVOhgjThxcBAOZB61QxkxI1qdhZCngNZADQloUasFpTRCoZC7hYiDydjXQ9U0vQIjUMyZAeb6aGLKi7VE1btwk8eOPnsEzxyZPhJV1GVoujWlbb6PHo44yIi3D5VPSBRJJuNUOXobSgQNAevpSDZBgZDZD
            [category] => Organization
            [category_list] => Array(
                [0] => stdClass Object(
                    [id] => 19850828628
                    [name] => Organization
                )
            )

            [name] => Side Pot Cavan
            [id] => 67433931
            [perms] => Array(
                [0] => ADMINISTER
                [1] => EDIT_PROFILE
                [2] => CREATE_CONTENT
                [3] => MODERATE_CONTENT
                [4] => CREATE_ADS
                [5] => BASIC_ADMIN
            )
        )

        [1] => stdClass Object(
            [access_token] => CAAVOhgjThxcBAD7t6VU3HJAz9AovBJ7OiNzeFRBEQcHDEyHzRmi8oZBMnUyBQHxqNPeTXZBzWaOhCs2ivNWVvHwi5MGJpAuzgsP3d3cVq4LYZBsxcQQbmB5ufZAct250ZBhfENZCFCZAqAPaWvhGFpI5FzM38PwEIZCIZAtdtcvQZC0gZDZD
            [category] => Cause
            [name] => James Morgan
            [id] => 2773587
            [perms] => Array(
                [0] => ADMINISTER
                [1] => EDIT_PROFILE
                [2] => CREATE_CONTENT
                [3] => MODERATE_CONTENT
                [4] => CREATE_ADS
                [5] => BASIC_ADMIN
            )
        )

        [2] => stdClass Object(
            [access_token] => CAAVOhgjThxcBAIdnByW9TV7ZAxOnBS42nZAWDFEHeb3hPe5lTEMVwzBuZBMiPB99qOM1ks8VafDxLIZBbZCHe8tkDrtjRcPw8DUtpvnBUsNWvqKxt4y7oub10SgHqxRS194At5HBTLJ0K4vpo7qWaXZCIJwZDZD
            [category] => Sports venue
            [name] => Galway Poker Festival
            [id] => 9751854
            [perms] => Array(
                [0] => ADMINISTER
                [1] => EDIT_PROFILE
                [2] => CREATE_CONTENT
                [3] => MODERATE_CONTENT
                [4] => CREATE_ADS
                [5] => BASIC_ADMIN
            )
        )
```

I have edited the IDs and tokens here for public use.

I am sure I am just missing a next trick to get these values.

Comment: thanks for editing, much easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods `getProperty()` and `getPropertyAsArray()` to get the values of a GraphObject. If you want to know what properties there are, use `getPropertyNames()`.

Since this is an array of data (multiple pages the user is admin of), it might be easier to use it as a simple array, like you are trying to - there is a method called `asArray()` which does exactly this:

```
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
$data = $graphObject->asArray();
```

Here's the reference for the Facebook GraphObject class: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/4.0.0

Comment: I like as array, this makes the reponse much cleaner. Thanks for this, i feel i am a little closer now.

Answer (score 0):

so i got a clue from the above answer and moved on:

my finished code was:

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

```
if (is_array($value)) {
    foreach ($value as $invalue) {
        $array =  (array) $invalue;


        foreach ($array as $key2 => $value2) {
            if ($key2=='access_token') {
                $c++;
                $ats[$c]=$value2;

            }
            if ($key2=='name') {

                $pagenames[$c]=$value2;

            }
            if ($key2=='id') {

                $ids[$c]=$value2;   

            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

So i got a nice clean array from $data = $graphObject->asArray();

then proceeded.

There was another object inside the array so i typecast that to array then run foreach loops over it to get the keys i wanted.

Not the prettiest but it did the job.

thanks